# Typescript destruct with spread operator

Tags: typescript

I have a question in typescipt with destruct and spread operator,
is possible to get the Sub interface attributes but Sample interface?
like

```
interface Sample {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  height: number;
}
interface Sub {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const sample: Sample = {
  name: "hi",
  age: 10,
  height: 190,
};
const sub: Sub = { ...sample };
console.log(sub);
// {name: 'hi', age: 10, height: 190}
// expect {name: 'hi', age: 10}
```

Comment: Interfaces and types exist only till compile time and not runtime, so no. This only restricts the types of the variables but does not do this (what you're expecting it to do).

Comment: @0xts It's not clearly worded, but the code definitely looks like they're asking about an instance of those interfaces, rather than the interfaces themselves.

Comment: You have to pick everything yourself, or you could use (the side effect of) [zod](https://zod.dev) to remove all extra properties

Comment: This is certainly possible with destructuring, but I believe you'd still need to specify which properties you are using, so you may as well just build the object (it would be clearer)

Answer (score 0):

Typescript doesn't affect the runtime behavior.

There is no error because the type system of the Typescript known as duck-typing only checks if the required fields are present and they are in the correct shape.

Example:

```
interface Sample {
  age: number;
  height: number;
}
interface Sub {
  name: string;
  age: number;
}
const sample: Sample = {
  age: 10,
  height: 190,
};
const sub: Sub = { ...sample }; // error, name is missing
```

However, `Sample` is a *subset* of the `Sub` and has all fields that `Sub` does.

The easiest solution would be destructing and taking the desired fields:

```
const { height, ...sub } = { ...sample }
```

Alternatively, you could create a `fromXtoY` function:

```
const fromSampleToSub = (x: Sample): Sub => {
  return {
    name: sample.name,
    age: sample.age,
  };
};

const sub = fromSampleToSub(sample)
```